Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception
Estoy creando un login pero al ingresar el usuario y la contraseña no me envia a la pagina de inicio y solo se queda en el archivo de usuario.php
<?php
// Configuración para mostrar errores
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include("../back/conexion.php");
session_start();
$conexion=conectar();

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;

 if($_SESSION['usuario'] == "takis"){
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = 1;
 }else if($_SESSION['usuario'] == "picafresa"){
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = 2;

 }else{
    echo"error";
 }
 
    $peticion = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '".$usuario."' AND contrasena = '".$contrasena."'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $peticion);
     

if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0 ){
    echo "<script>window.location='../Pages/home.html'</script>";
    


 }else{ 
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Contraseña incorrecta\");</script>";
echo "<script>window.location='../index.php'</script>";
  }

?>

y uso un conexion.php para conectar a la base de datos
<?php   
function conectar(){ 
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbusuario = "";
    $dbcontrasena = "";
    $dbname = "servicio";


    $conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $dbusuario, $dbcontrasena, $dbname);
    return $conexion;

    if (!$conexion) {
        die('Fallo la conexion: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
}   
 ?>


y me da el error
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/SistemaPsicologia/back/conexion.php:9 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/SistemaPsicologia/back/conexion.php(9): mysqli_connect() #1 /var/www/html/SistemaPsicologia/back/usuario.php(9): conectar() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/SistemaPsicologia/back/conexion.php on line 9
Me podrian ayudar por favor, ya no se que mas hacer para que quede.

no se esta estableciendo la coneccion hay un error al intentar conectarte a la base de datos.

Si tu código en conectar.php es realmente así, estas pasando un usuario y clave en blanco al tratar de crear la conexión a la base de datos. Por otra parte, el código que aparece despúes del return nunca se ejecuta, precisamente por estar después del return.
